# How do you define a variable in one function and change it in another with the first function recognizing it

Tags: python, function, while-loop

How would I make a function where one variable (exit) determines whether a 'while' loop runs or not and be able to change it in a different function so that the while loop in the first function will stop

```
    while exit == 0:
       option = (raw_input("What would you like to do? "))
       if option == exit:
          exit()
    def exit():
       exit = 1
```

That is just an example of what I am trying to do.

When I try running it it doesnt leave the while loop and in doing so doesn't end the program.  How can I make it so that the while loop recognizes that exit is now 1 and leaves the loop?
Sorry if the question isn't very good because this is my first time using stackoverflow to ask a question.

ADDITION: I want to kno how to change the variable across functions because I will be doing that in parts of the program.  Also, I am going to be saving data before exit so that is why I have the 'exit' in a different function

Comment: You could have used a module variable defined in the module scope and use it in the different function (to answer your question). Exiting a loop is way different, `if option == "exit": exit = 1` would have done the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem here is scope - `exit` is local to the function `exit()` so doesn't affect the variable `exit` in the loop scope.

A better solution is this:

```
exit = False
while not exit:
    option = raw_input("What would you like to do?")
    if option == "exit":
        exit = True
```

Or simply:

```
while True:
    option = raw_input("What would you like to do?")
    if option == "exit":
        break
```

Note the use of `True` and `False` over `1` and `0` - this is more pythonic, as what you mean here is truth values, not integers. I also changed to compare to the string `"exit"`, as I presumed that was what you wanted, not comparing the user input to the value of `exit`.

If your problem is you want to have the same scope, you might want to make your code part of a class.

```
class Doer: #Naturally, give it a real name based on it's purpose.
    def __init__(self):
        self.exit = False
        while not self.exit:
            option = raw_input("What would you like to do?")
            if option == "exit":
                self.exit()

    def exit(self):
        self.exit = True
```

Here `exit` is an instance variable (hence being accessed from `self`) and therefore both times we are referencing the same variable.

If your code is not a simplification of a more complex problem, this is largely overkill, as one of the first solutions would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `break` in place of your `exit` call and throw your `exit` function away.

Answer (score 1):

first your variable and function should not have the same name, but here is something that might  work for you:

```
status = True
while status:
   option = (raw_input("What would you like to do? "))
   if option == "exit":
      break
   elif option == "do_something":
      status = do_something()
   elif option == "do_something_and_exit":
      status = do_something_and_exit()
   else:
      print "I don't understand"

def do_something():
    #do something awesome
    return True
def do_something():
    #do someting awesome
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

Such variable looks like state of some object. To make this object serve as function you can make it callable

```
class Ask(object):
    def __call__(self):
        self.exit = False
        while not self.exit:
            option = (raw_input("What would you like to do? "))
            if option == 'exit':
                break
    def quit():
        self.exit = True

ask  = Ask()

>>> ask()
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to change variables from another function is to *return* the value and then assign it locally.  In your code example, it looks like this:

```
while exit == 0:
   option = (raw_input("What would you like to do? "))
   if option == 'exit':
      exit = set_exit()

def set_exit():
   return 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems I'm a bit late to the answer party, but here's how to use closures and mutation (and ancient programming trick) to do it.

This will work in python3 (in python2 you can do the same thing, but have to use a list to hold your variable).

```
x = 1

def mutateX(new):
    nonlocal x     # you will have to use the 'global' keyword if this function is defined in the body of a module
    x = new

print(x)  # --> 1
mutateX(2)
print(x)  # --> 2
```

This is not what you should be doing in this case (just use `break`), but it answers the question you asked in the title of your question.